# How to change an sprite animation in andengine for android?

Tags: android, jquery-animate, sprite, andengine

When creating an sprite object I use `.animate(250);` to start looping through my sprite. This works fine.

But when I in my collision detection try to run something like `.animate(new long[] { 250, 250, 500, 500 }, 0, 3, true);` it only shows frame number 0.

This function also works if I call it when I create my object the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I think is becuse the collision is detected alltime, try first set a tag in you Sprite, for example:

```
AnimatedSprite elemen1 = new AnimatedSprite(...);
elemen1.setTag(1);
```

in you method of collision:

```
if(elemen1.getTag==1 && elemen1.collidesWith(elementX)){
       elemen1.setTag(0);
       elemen1.animate(new long[] { 250, 250, 500, 500 }, 0, 3, true);
}
```

Because if the animation never go to second frame is because all time is starting, best regards.